# Does GD2 library in imagine of Yii core framework, support of GIF multi layers (animated)?

Tags: php, yii2, gd

This code return "1" always!

```
\yii\imagine\Image::$driver = [\yii\imagine\Image::DRIVER_GD2];
$imagine = \yii\imagine\Image::getImagine();
$image = $imagine->open('image.gif');
echo count($image->layers()) . " layers";
```

Does GD2 library in [imagine](http://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of [Yii](http://yiiframework.com/) core framework, support of GIF multi layers (animated) ?

Comment: The GD library does not support multiple layers. Imagick does.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois   Do you sure? (http://libgd.github.io/manuals/2.1.1/files/gd_gif_out-c.html#gdImageGifAnimBeginPtr)

Comment: At least the PHP implementation doesn't.